# Is it possible in main app to use dependancies from added dependancies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

The problem I have is that I have a `Library` which I want to use in the `Main App`. In the `Library` I have added external libraries, and the question is, is it possible to use directly code of this external libraries in `Main App` despite of that these libraries are not added directly to `Main App` but to my `Library`?

I've added my `Library` to `pom.xml` in `Main App` and I can use the code that is written there, but I have problem using `Library` classes that extends external library classes, because Spring throws `ClassNotFoundException`

I've tried `@ComponentScan` in `Main App` and as argument I passed the main package of `Library` (`com.project.common.starter`), but it helped only with Components of the `Library`, but no external ones

---***EDIT:***
my ***Library*** pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project.starter</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-commons-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project-commons-starter</name>
    <description>project-commons-starter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.external.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>external-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my ***Main App*** pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>main-app-name</name>
    <description>main-app-desc</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project.starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-commons-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

Class in ***Library*** that probably causes problem:

```java
package com.project.starter.service;

import com.external.ExternalLibraryProcessor;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LibraryProcessor implements ExternalLibraryProcessor {

    @Override
    public void process() {
       String context = MDC.get(ContextUtils.REQUEST_CONTEXT)      
       doSmth...
    }
}
```

my ***MainPortalApplication*** :

```java
package com.project

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.project","com.project.starter"})
public class MainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
       
    }
}
```

ContextUtils.class:

```java
public class ContextUtils {

    private ContextUtils() {
    }
    public static final String REQUEST_CONTEXT = "requestContext";
}
```

When I run application I get:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/***/.m2/repository/com/project/project-commons-starter/0.0.1/project-commons-starter-0.0.1.jar!/com/project/starter/commons/ContextUtils.class];
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.project.starter.service.LibraryProcessor] for bean with name 'libraryProcessor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/***/.m2/repository/com/project/project-commons-starter/0.0.1/project-commons-starter-0.0.1.jar!/com/project/starter/service/LibraryProcessor.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/external/library/ExternalLibraryProcessor
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` is a _runtime_ problem. You're not launching your program correctly.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Probably, that's why I'm asking here. As the details of the ClassNotFoundException it says that it cannot find a class from external library dependency which is extended in my library. When I add this external dependency directly to Main app,  it runs and work normally. I just wanted, if it is possible, to not add dependency twice - in main app and my library

Comment: _Transitive dependencies_ are normally included, but you didn't provide enough information for us to identify your problem.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question and added more details. If it's missing any important data please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: _How_ do you run your application? What specific steps do you take to launch it?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- it's a Spring boot app and i'm testing it locally using intellij. On prod mvn clean package and then java - jar app.jar

Comment: Did you include the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in your `build` section?

Comment: Yes, in main app yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was that I was using wrong maven command to compile my `Library`:

`mvn install:install-file [...]`

When using above `.pom` file has no dependencies which where included in `Library`.

When changed to `mvn install` it started working well - `.pom` file started to look like it should and `Main App` recognized transient dependencies.